# Can a SQL Server Docker container run on Windows Server core 2022 ("linux" cannot be used on this platform)

Tags: sql-server, windows, docker, powershell, server-core

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

Error:

> image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform

I'm running docker on a Windows Server Core 2022 platform

- Client app is Docker application version 0.8.0
- Server shows two images  ltsc2022 and 1809-amd64 [nanoserver images]
- Server version is 20.10.7
- Kernel version is 10.0.20348

I wasn't aware that Linux was installed so the error is a bit confusing. Does Windows Server Core 2022 come preloaded with Linux?   What does it mean when the error states "linux" cannot be used on this platform?

Looking at the Task Manager, services tab, shows that Docker Engine is up and running.

Comment: The docker images of SQL Server are Linux based; this is why you're getting an error about Linux. I haven't looked into too far, but I suspect Linux containers, via Docker, are not (yet) supported on Windows Server 2022 (core).

Comment: That seems problematic, given [Update- Beta program for SQL Server on Windows container is suspended](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/update-beta-program-for-sql-server-on-windows-container-is/ba-p/2516639) so there won't be a Windows Container version of SQL Server.

Comment: Windows Server supports only Windows containers. You'll need to create a Linux VM with Docker to run the official SQL Server Linux images. Although you could create your own custom docker Windows Server core image with SQL Server installed, that is an entirely unsupported configuration so do so at your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest as it's Linux based. You say you already pulled ltsc2022 and 1809-amd64 [nanoserver images], so you can install SQL Server 2019 on either of them as I've already done that, see the following link for an example: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/polybase-scale-out-group-in-azure-for-free