# Docker Engine: create image for SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, docker

I want to create an image described like here:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#operation/ImageCreate

but with SQL Server Express.

So I tried

```
../images/create?fromImage=microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express
```

but what I get is:

```
{
    "message": "pull access denied for microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied"
}
```

I figured out that I somehow have to add `ACCEPT_EULA=Y` for this to work. But how do I add it in this Post Operation? Or is there another way?

Comment: Microsoft isn't doing SQL Server on Windows containers any more, ref: [Update- Beta program for SQL Server on Windows container is suspended](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/update-beta-program-for-sql-server-on-windows-container-is/ba-p/2516639). Try using `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server` with `MSSQL_PID=Express` instead. See [mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server)

Answer (score 0):

You can pull a Docker Windows Server Core image, and install SQL Server (any ediiton) into it, see this other answer: [Can a SQL Server Docker container run on Windows Server core 2022 ("linux" cannot be used on this platform)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69966817/can-a-sql-server-docker-container-run-on-windows-server-core-2022-linux-canno/69983314#69983314)